# How to fix "discord.ext.commands.errors.MissingRequiredArgument: ctx is a required argument that is missing." in discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'm trying do a simple bot with subclass to handler the commands but i got this error

Here Are the TraceBack:

> Ignoring exception in command teste:
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "/home/mrtrue/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/bot.py", line 863, in invoke
>       await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
>     File "/home/mrtrue/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 721, in invoke
>       await self.prepare(ctx)
>     File "/home/mrtrue/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 685, in prepare
>       await self._parse_arguments(ctx)
>     File "/home/mrtrue/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 599, in _parse_arguments
>       transformed = await self.transform(ctx, param)
>     File "/home/mrtrue/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 445, in transform
>       raise MissingRequiredArgument(param)
>   discord.ext.commands.errors.MissingRequiredArgument: ctx is a required argument that is missing.

And here are the code:

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import inspect

class BotLibertarin(commands.Bot):
    client = discord.Client()

    @client.event
    async def on_message(self,message):
        print(f"message from {message.author} what he said {message.content}")
        await self.process_commands(message)
class CommandsHandler(BotLibertarin):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(command_prefix=".")

        members = inspect.getmembers(self)
        for name, member in members:
            if isinstance(member,commands.Command):
                if member.parent is None:
                    self.add_command(member)

    @commands.command()
    async def teste(self,ctx):
        await ctx.channel.send("teste")
```

Comment: I'm a bit confused. Is this a bot.py main file for the bot? Or is it a cog?
You don't actually need a commands handler to process commands. It should be carried out automatically if you've setup your events correctly.

Comment: ah i did it cuz the commands doesn't worked and it's a main file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I really suggest that you spend time reading the [docs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html).
I'd also remind you that it's against ToS to send messages without a specific command being issued (such as !commandname) [Even though no one follows ToS apparently].

Either way. Try this:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

client = commands.Bot(command.prefix='!')

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    print(f"message from {message.author} what he said {message.content}")
    await message.channel.send(message.content)

@client.command()
async def teste(ctx):
    await ctx.channel.send("teste")
```

Comment: I reccomend using a consistent pair of quotes for strings, especially when answering a question where somebody has already used a certain pair of quotes consistently. Also this will return a Syntax Error as your indentation is incorrect (probably someting went wrong when copy pasting).

Comment: Mhm. The quotes are because I had to transfer it between devices on slack. Just edited it. Yeah. fixed that too.

Comment: Don't forget the indentation in the second import statement and @async def teste(ctx).

Comment: Cheers. Idk why it has to be so painful ;-;

Comment: Sorry to be annoying, but "await ctx.channel.send('teste')" is still indented too far.

Comment: LOL that's worked but idk why the version i did with OOP doesn't work